# ASP.NET WebApi returns XML or json based on the request header

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

In my `ASP.NET` project, all `WebApi` reply with a `json`. For this reason in `WebApiConfig.cs` I set

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Now, I have to change only one webapi to returns XML based on the request in the header.

What is the best practice for that? Is there any example?

Comment: You should read about content negotiations in web API

Answer (score 1):

[image]add this  to your config :

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

then you have xml and json serialization together at the same time ,
when you set accept header of request to "application/xml , xml/text" then you get xml and if you set header to "application/json , json/text" then you get json result 
it's called [content negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

other approach is to serialize the object to xml in the specific method

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I updated `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
}
```

Then in the webapi where I want to reply with `XML`

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCollections(int Id)
{
    List<CollectionDTO> result = _collectionsLogic.GetCollections(Id);

    IContentNegotiator negotiator = this.Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();

    ContentNegotiationResult resultFormatted = negotiator.Negotiate(
            typeof(List<CollectionDTO>), this.Request, this.Configuration.Formatters);

    if (result == null)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent<List<CollectionDTO>>(
                      result,
                      resultFormatted.Formatter,
                      resultFormatted.MediaType.MediaType
        )};
    }
}
```

If I call this webapi with `Postman`, for example, and I insert in the header `Accept` equals `application/xml`, I receive the result in `XML` format, otherwise in `json`